# Remove everything after an empty row on a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a quick question that I cannot figure out. I am reading some results from an output file using the code below and stored as a list in R that can be seen in the picture. I want to delete all of the information after an empty row, in other words, it would be everything after line 42:

[image: result of the above code]

Does anybody know anything that I could use? I tried using `gsub` was I was not very successful.

Thanks for all of the help I am new to programming in R. Again any help is very much appreciated.

```
LoadFFA <- function(filename, folder.out, TYPE = "PeakFQ_17C",
                    colStandard = TRUE){ # standardize column output names

    require(data.table)
        if(grepl("PEAKFQSA",TYPE)){ # PeakfqSA Bulleting 17C analysis
          text.list<-lapply(fileinput,readLines)
          skip.rows<-sapply(text.list, grep, pattern = '^Ann. Exc. Prob.\\s+EMA Est.')-1
          PFA <- lapply(seq_along(text.list),function(i) read.delim(fileinput[i],skip=skip.rows[i],sep="\n",stringsAsFactors = TRUE,blank.lines.skip = FALSE))
        }
```

EDIT

I don't know if I could upload directly so here is the google drive link.
Also, here is the command to run the function LoadFFA("03606500peaks.out","D:/Documents/hydraulic.failures","PEAKFQSA"). The screenshot is the result using print(PFA).

The reason why I am using a loop is because I am reading multiple files (output files) and they have a lot of data, multiple lenghts, and I am reading the data beginning Ann.Exc.Prob. and as per the screenshot provided I would like to end after line 42 (after a full empty row). I hope that clears some confusion.

Basically read the output files, start reading on "Ann.Exc.Prob" and end until the end of that data (line 42 for this particular file). I am using a function because I am running several times.

Again, sorry for the trouble. Thank you for your time and I appreciate your patience.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PGbGWIHFj7IQRevTAEfqqA9Okg4fz7Mg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe the question becomes more clear if you add a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please include your minimal sample data as R code, not as a screenshot. This makes it easier for us to try out your code, reproduce the problem and find answers. THX :-)

Comment: Generally you should read your data into a `data.table` (e. g. via `read.csv` or `read.table`) or try to convert your data into a data.table via `mydata <- read.csv(fileinput, sep = "")`. You can pick the wanted lines then easily once you have decided which rows to keep/drop vie the "row number" (index) selector, e. g. `result <- mydata[1:42, ]`.

Comment: Updates have been added and files have been uploaded

Comment: How would I go about it if the length varies? That is why I thought that I could tell R to delete everything after an empty row.